# callback on delete from database?

Tags: django, model

My Django app uses Amazon S3 storage for the user's data files that they have uploaded.  I store a pointer (using the uuid) to the file in the model:

model.py:

```
class Gedcom(models.Model):
"""Gedcom model."""

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36, default="")
```

Is there a way to perform a callback of sorts when a gedcom item is deleted (say through either the admin interface or via my other code) that a method is called so that I can delete that file from S3?

I could run a management function as part of a cron job that delete unlinked file on S3 if they no longer exist in the local database, but I'm wondering if there is another way to do this that is cleaner?

Comment: Yes. Check `signals`.

Comment: Thanks @JosefKorbel.  Looks like a pre_delete signal is just what I need.

Comment: I would recommend post_delete,  so you are sure that deletion won't fail for some reason and you aren't left with reference to deleted file

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov  - makes sense.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a post_delete signal is the way to go:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Gedcom, dispatch_uid='gedcom_s3_delete')
def s3_delete(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    if settings.enable_s3:
        try:
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
            file = s3.Object(settings.s3_bucket, instance.uuid)
            file.delete()
        except:
            print("Unable to delete from S3")
```